# asp.net MVC password recovery tool not working

Tags: mysql, asp.net-membership, password-recovery

I am using the password recovery control in an ASP.NET MVC 2 web app.  When I click the submit button without a username, it indicates the username is missing with an asterisk.  If I put in an a username the form submits but nothing happens.  Am I missing something here?

Web.config:

```
<system.net>
  <mailSettings>
    <smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="yyy@zzz.com">
      <network host="mail.zzz.com" userName="yyy@zzz.com" 
        password="xxxxx" enableSsl="false" />               
    </smtp>
  </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

machine.config

```
<membership defaultProvider="MySQLMembershipProvider">
<providers>
<add name="MySQLMembershipProvider" 
type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLMembershipProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.3.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" 
autogenerateschema="true"
connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer" 
enablePasswordRetrieval="false" 
enablePasswordReset="true" 
requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" 
applicationName="/" 
requiresUniqueEmail="true" 
passwordFormat="Hashed" 
maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" 
minRequiredPasswordLength="6" 
minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1" 
passwordAttemptWindow="10" 
passwordStrengthRegularExpression="" />
</providers>
</membership>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your configuration you're using hashed passwords and have password retrieval disabled. This means you cannot recover passwords (because they're hashed). You can only reset them.

This is a secure setup, so don't change it. But be aware that you cannot "recover" passwords when they're hashed.

If your requirements specify that passwords must be recoverable then you'll have to change the passwordFormat to Encrypted and set enablePasswordRetrieval="true". But know that any hashed passwords and password answers in your database will need to be re-entered by the user because the current values will be 'corrupt' as far as the provider is concerned. To enforce this change over, you could override the Authenticate method in your login page and check the user's LastPasswordChange date then redirect them to a page to reconfigure their password and answer so they can login properly.

One last thing to mention though is, encrypted passwords are retrievable because they can be decrypted. This means they are less secure. So stick with hashed passwords if you can.